# Error Call to a member function paginate() on string

Tags: laravel, pagination

I'm currently working on a search data filter and when I click it it's an error call to a member function paginate() on string

Controller:

```
public function index(Request $request) {
    if ($request->has('search')) {
       $data = rekap::where('customer','LIKE','%' .$request->search. '%'->paginate(5));
    } else {
        $data = rekap::paginate(5);
    }
        
    return view('rekap', compact('data'));
}
```

View:

```
<form action="/rekap" method="GET">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Cari..." name="search">
        <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
</form>

{{ $data->links() }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your return like this

```
 if($request->has('search')){
        $data = rekap::where('customer','LIKE','%' .$request->search. '%')->paginate(5);
    }else{
        $data = rekap::paginate(5);
    }
return view('blade name here')->with([
        'data' => $data,
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it in single query

```
public function index(Request $request){
        $data = rekap::when($request->filled('search'), function($q){
            $q->where('customer', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->input('search') . '%');
        })
        ->paginate(5);

        return view('rekap', compact('data'));
}
```